# Less than Greater than signs in pyscript

Tags: python, html, pyscript

I am trying to test this code on the webpage

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/pyscript-use-python-code-in-html-f7c8b49486a4

When I test this code it looks like it is complaining about the "<" sign inside the py-script tag. Do I need some type of escape character here?

```
<head>
    <title>Matplotlib</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
        - matplotlib
    </py-env>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mpl"></div>
    <py-script output="mpl">
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import numpy as np

# First create the x and y coordinates of the points.
n_angles = 36
n_radii = 8
min_radius = 0.25
radii = np.linspace(min_radius, 0.95, n_radii)

angles = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_angles, endpoint=False)
angles = np.repeat(angles[..., np.newaxis], n_radii, axis=1)
angles[:, 1::2] += np.pi / n_angles

x = (radii * np.cos(angles)).flatten()
y = (radii * np.sin(angles)).flatten()
z = (np.cos(radii) * np.cos(3 * angles)).flatten()

# Create the Triangulation; no triangles so Delaunay triangulation created.
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)

# Mask off unwanted triangles.
triang.set_mask(np.hypot(x[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1),
y[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1)) < min_radius) fig1, ax1=plt.subplots() ax1.set_aspect('equal') tpc=ax1.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='flat' )
fig1.colorbar(tpc) ax1.set_title('tripcolor of Delaunay triangulation, flat shading') fig1 </py-script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below is the error I am getting. How do I address the operator issue or am I wrong and issue is else where?

```
JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 421, in eval_code CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 237, in __init__ self.ast = next(self._gen) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 141, in _parse_and_compile_gen mod = compile(source, filename, mode, flags | ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 24 y[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1))< min_radius) fig1, ax1=plt.subplots() ax1.set_aspect('equal') tpc=ax1.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='flat' ) ^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax )
```

Comment: What if you change the operator or remove it entirely? Does the error still happen? I'm just wondering why you think it's that operator that's causing the issue. Also maybe it's something I haven't seen before but the "fig1" at the end of those statements is weird to me, I don't get what that's doing there.

Comment: Googles says this is from the [Triplot Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/triplot_demo.html). It looks like you just copied a chunk of code and expected to be able to run it as is without formatting it correctly.

Comment: You DO have a syntax error in that line.  `< min_radius) fig1`.  You have a bunch of lines concatenated into one.  The `fig1` and the `ax1.set...` lines should be on separate lines.

Comment: Yes I am testing to see if I have this set up right so Yes I did copy what I thought was working code. My graphs are not working either and it would have been harder to explain my code than this code that already has an explanation. I may not have my environment set up correctly The error line that it specifies is the lne with  "<".  In python its not an issue. But in html file it may be an issue. I am staring to have my doubts on the post itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of source code lines that are folded together. This causes Python syntax errors.

Replace starting at `# Mask of unwanted triangles` with this:

```
# Mask off unwanted triangles.
triang.set_mask(np.hypot(x[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1),
y[triang.triangles].mean(axis=1)) < min_radius)
fig1, ax1=plt.subplots()
ax1.set_aspect('equal')
tpc=ax1.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='flat' )
fig1.colorbar(tpc)
ax1.set_title('tripcolor of Delaunay triangulation, flat shading')
fig1
</py-script>
```

The program will generate an image like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you John. JsException(PythonError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 421, in eval_code CodeRunner( File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 237, in __init__ self.ast = next(self._gen) File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_pyodide/_base.py", line 141, in _parse_and_compile_gen mod = compile(source, filename, mode, flags | ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST) File "", line 27 tpc=ax1.tripcolor(triang, z, shading='flat' ) fig1.colorbar(tpc) ax1.set_title('tripcolor of Delaunay triangulation, ^ SyntaxError: unterminated string

Comment: (Error Continue:) literal (detected at line 27)

Comment: Works in python but my issue as stated in question was running it in html. Did it work in html for you?

Comment: @LeoTorres - I think you have made a copy and paste mistake. I uploaded my answer to my web server. Go here and compare the source to what you are using (right-click view page source) https://jhanley.com/examples/pyscript/matplotlib.html